# Remove “:80” from a URL phpbb + phpBB SEO extension

Tags: phpbb

I have a problem with the urls in phpbb3.2 after installing the phpBB SEO - usu + no-duplicate from here https://github.com/phpbb-seo.
I use advance mode.
I have Lightspeed server in my hosting.
I copied the .htaccess file to the root of the forum folder.
when I going to https://example.com/forum im getting an error: "This site can’t provide a secure connection."
if I choose ignore, the site loads with a security warning.
the bigger issue is when I click a forum name, Im redirected to https://example.com**:80**/forum/xyz.html
*where is the port :80 coming from ?* and **how do I get rid of it** as a start?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 # You may need to un-comment the following lines
 # Options +FollowSymlinks
 # To make sure that rewritten dir or file (/|.html) will not load dir.php 
in case it exist
 # Options -MultiViews
 # REMEBER YOU ONLY NEED TO STARD MOD REWRITE ONCE
 RewriteEngine On

 # Uncomment the statement below if you want to make use of
 # HTTP authentication and it does not already work.
 # This could be required if you are for example using PHP via Apache CGI.
 # RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

 # REWRITE BASE
 RewriteBase /

 # HERE IS A GOOD PLACE TO FORCE CANONICAL DOMAIN
 # Define fully qualified ssl aware protocol
 # RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|[0-9]+s)$
 # RewriteRule ^.*$ - [env=HttpFullProto:http%2://]
 # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com:80$ [NC]
 # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:HttpFullProto}domain.com:80/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

 # DO NOT GO FURTHER IF THE REQUESTED FILE / DIR DOES EXISTS
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule . - [L]
 # FORUM INDEX REWRITERULE WOULD STAND HERE IF USED. "forum" REQUIRES TO BE SET AS FORUM INDEX
 # RewriteRule ^forum/forum\.html$ /forum/index.php [QSA,L,NC]
 # FORUM ALL MODES
 RewriteRule ^forum/(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/viewforum.php?f=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
 # TOPIC WITH VIRTUAL FOLDER ALL MODES
 RewriteRule ^forum/(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 [QSA,L,NC]
 # TOPIC WITHOUT FORUM ID & DELIM ALL MODES
 RewriteRule ^forum/([a-z0-9_-]*)/?(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/viewtopic.php?forum_uri=$1&t=$3&start=$5 [QSA,L,NC]
 # PROFILES ALL MODES WITH ID
 RewriteRule ^forum/(member|[a-z0-9_-]*-u)([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
 # USER MESSAGES ALL MODES WITH ID
 RewriteRule ^forum/(member|[a-z0-9_-]*-u)([0-9]+)-(topics|posts)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/search.php?author_id=$2&sr=$3&start=$5 [QSA,L,NC]
 # GROUPS ALL MODES
 RewriteRule ^forum/(group|[a-z0-9_-]*-g)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/memberlist.php?mode=group&g=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
 # POSTS
 RewriteRule ^forum/post([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum/viewtopic.php?p=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
 # ACTIVE TOPICS
 RewriteRule ^forum/active-topics(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/search.php?search_id=active_topics&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
 # UNANSWERED TOPICS
 RewriteRule ^forum/unanswered(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/search.php?search_id=unanswered&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
 # NEW POSTS
 RewriteRule ^forum/newposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/search.php?search_id=newposts&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
 # UNREAD POSTS
 RewriteRule ^forum/unreadposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/search.php?search_id=unreadposts&start=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
 # THE TEAM
 RewriteRule ^forum/the-team\.html$ /forum/memberlist.php?mode=team [QSA,L,NC]
 # HERE IS A GOOD PLACE TO ADD OTHER PHPBB RELATED REWRITERULES

 # FORUM WITHOUT ID & DELIM ALL MODES
 # THESE LINES MUST BE LOCATED AT THE END OF YOUR HTACCESS TO WORK PROPERLY
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^forum/([a-z0-9_-]+?)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /forum/viewforum.php?forum_uri=$1&start=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
 # FIX RELATIVE PATHS : FILES
 RewriteRule ^forum/(style\.php|ucp\.php|mcp\.php|faq\.php|posting\.php|download/file\.php|report\.php|adm/index\.php|cron\.php)$ /forum/$1 [QSA,L,NC,R=301]
 # FIX RELATIVE PATHS : IMAGES
 RewriteRule ^forum/(styles/.*|images/.*|assets/.*|ext/.*)$ /forum/$1 [QSA,L,NC,R=301]
 #
 # The following 3 lines will rewrite URLs passed through the front controller
 # to not require app.php in the actual URL. In other words, a controller is
 # by default accessed at /app.php/my/controller, but can also be accessed at
 # /my/controller
 #
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /forum/app.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
# With Apache 2.4 the "Order, Deny" syntax has been deprecated and moved from
# module mod_authz_host to a new module called mod_access_compat (which may be
# disabled) and a new "Require" syntax has been introduced to mod_authz_host.
# We could just conditionally provide both versions, but unfortunately Apache
# does not explicitly tell us its version if the module mod_version is not
# available. In this case, we check for the availability of module
# mod_authz_core (which should be on 2.4 or higher only) as a best guess.

<IfModule mod_version.c>
     <IfVersion < 2.4>
          <Files "config.php">
               Order Allow,Deny
               Deny from All
          </Files>
          <Files "common.php">
               Order Allow,Deny
               Deny from All
          </Files>
     </IfVersion>
     <IfVersion >= 2.4>
          <Files "config.php">
               Require all denied
          </Files>
          <Files "common.php">
               Require all denied
          </Files>
     </IfVersion>
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_version.c>
     <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
          <Files "config.php">
               Order Allow,Deny
               Deny from All
          </Files>
          <Files "common.php">
               Order Allow,Deny
               Deny from All
          </Files>
     </IfModule>
     <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
          <Files "config.php">
               Require all denied
          </Files>
          <Files "common.php">
               Require all denied
          </Files>
     </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```